# How can I solve this ggplot2 error message in R Studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I've installed ggplot2 and rlang but keep getting this error. I'm using R version 4.2.1. Can someone pleas tell me how to solve this error?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘rlang’
```

Ive tried remove and reinstall packages but no luck so far

Comment: Run `install.packages("rlang")`